# firestore doc.data is not a function error appears when using docChanges method

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a chat app that and I'd like to listen to doc changes to push new messages as opposed to re-rendering every doc with a change.

Firebase has a solution with the following:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots

this is also the same solution I found on Stack, but for some reason it's not working for me.

```js
  getMessages(docId: string) {
    const msgCollection = collection(getFirestore(getApp()), `matches`, `${docId}`, `messages`);
    return query(msgCollection, orderBy('createdAt', 'asc'));
  }
  
    getMessages(matchId: string) {
    const q = this.chatSvc.getMessages(matchId);
    onSnapshot(q, (QuerySnapshot: any) => {
        QuerySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((doc) => {
          this.messages.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        });
        console.log('mess', this.messages)
    });
  }
```

It was working before i added docChanges(), but once i added it I'm getting this console error:

```js
zone.js:218 Uncaught TypeError: doc.data is not a function
    at chat.page.ts:61:39
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at chat.page.ts:60:36
    at angular-fire.js:207:29
    at angular-fire.js:163:45
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:409:30)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26518:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:408:56)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:169:47)
    at NgZone.run (core.mjs:26372:28)
```

As far as I can see, my code matches the example in the firebase doc with the exception of:
if (change.type === "added")

The plan is to add the conditional statement once I get docChanges() working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`docChanges()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docchanges) method returns the following `Array<DocumentChange <T>>`. Therefore in your code the variable `doc` will be of type [`DocumentChange`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange). Then inside `DocumentChange` you have a property called `doc` of type `QueryDocumentSnapshot` which would have the method [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#data). Therefore in your code you have to do:

```
this.messages.push({ ...doc.doc.data(), id: doc.doc.id });
```